# Cannot post / error while using POST method in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to built an simple Todo List App using node js. I want to make middleware route once an activity is added. What changes are to be done to make it redirect to homepage('/')

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var jsonParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "todo"
});

con.connect(function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected");
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM doActs";
    console.log("In our main route function");
    con.query(sql, (err, results, fields)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log(results);
        res.render('main', {data: results});
    });
});

app.post('/addvalue', jsonParser, (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    var sql = `INSERT INTO doActs (activity) VALUES ("${req.body.addAction}")`;
    con.query(sql, (err, results)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("We added the data: " + req.body.addAction);
        res.redirect(307, '/');
    });
});

app.listen(7777);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `307` code due to a `POST /addvalue` call, trying to redirect them to the `/` page. A `307` response represents a "Temporary Redirect," which indicates that the service you are looking for has been relocated to the location provided on the `Location` header. [See MDN documentation regarding this status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307)

A `307` response will trigger a new request to the new `Location` but will maintain the headers and the body of the original request. Meaning that the browser will reuse the `method` of the request. You probably want the user to be redirected to the `/` page, using a `GET` request to get the updated `toActs`. So, a `303` response would be more appropriate. As the [docs says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `303 See Other` redirect status response code indicates that the redirects don't link to the newly uploaded resources but another page (such as a confirmation page or an upload progress page).

Answer (score 0):

307 redirects to the same method. (post -> post)

Send only success or not and add `href.location = '/'` to your browser

```js
app.post('/addvalue', jsonParser, (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    var sql = `INSERT INTO doActs (activity) VALUES ("${req.body.addAction}")`;
    con.query(sql, (err, results)=>{
        if (err) return res.status(500).end();
        console.log("We added the data: " + req.body.addAction);
        return res.status(200).end();
    });
});
```

Comment: This works fine and removes error but it is not redirecting me to the original site (home page '/').